# 'The Underlying Ethos'

Tags: terminology

The other day I stumbled upon a tricky English sentence:

'In a significant departure from the underlying ethos of the Thatcher era, Cameron declared, in his speech, that...'

I'm not too sure about the meaning of 'underlying' here. The dictionary claims four distinctive meanings

1) concealed, hidden 
2) basic, fundamental 
3) lying under 
4) prior, taking precedence

How do I know which one is right? The first and the second one could, in my opinion, easily fit in there, changing the subtle meaning though. How do I figure out the meaning of a word, when several definitions fit it?

Thanks

Comment: The word "underlying" is really not necessary here; *ethos* does not require such an adjective. Moreover, a spatially figurative metaphor is jarring with *ethos*. Finally, "departing from an underlying ethos" is awkward. We need a "murky prose" tag. I don't have enough rep to create it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't always tell unless you know more about the subject being discussed.

Regarding the sentence you quote, I don't think there was anything concealed or hidden about Margaret Thatcher's ideology.  So in this sentence "underlying" is used to mean "basic" or "fundamental".

If you are unsure of which of two or more definitions applies in a particular sentence on some other occasion, then reading more about the topic or discussing it with someone would be ways to help you decide which meaning is applicable.

Comment: I suspect you are correct, but it also conveys an impression of *unstated*, as any attempt to describe what lay behind Thatcherism tended to be superficial or incomplete.

Comment: Knowing UK politics, Cameron will expect the listener to be familiar with Thatcher. Her ideology is well documented, well read and rested on the work of widely published intellectuals. He is using *underlying* in the almost literal sense: The fundamental values upon which Thatcherism rested. He'd never expect people to infer that there's any mystery about Thatcher's views. Love her or hate her, people knew what she stood for.